# Python, Suds, giving a value to wsdlsoap:operation SoapAction?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soap-client, suds

I'm new to this, I've successfully been web scraping from this website but having difficulties with this operation. The difference this time is that I need to change the value of "soapAction".

```
<wsdl:operation name="assignPartNumber">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
```

In previous scripts, I've got all my information from the operation name. If I run this in my whole script, I get the error message,
*INVALID DATA IN ACTION CODE FIELD. PLEASE ENTER 1 OR 2*

How would I change the value of soapAction? Thanks

I would usually get information from a soap operation, such as assignPartNumber, by using this line

```
data = mylogin.service.assignPartNumber(user, info1, info2, info3)
```